# Is there some way to initialize all fields of dataclass without explicit assignment of None values?

Tags: python, initialization, python-dataclasses

I have a following code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass 
class foo:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    
tmp = foo(x=None, y=None, z=None, a=None, b=None, c=None)
print(tmp.x) # --> None

tmp1 = foo(x=None) # --> TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', and 'c'
```

Is there some "pythonic"/shorter/easier way to initialize dataclass `foo` with None values compared to explicit initialization with passing named parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default values, i.e. like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing as t

@dataclass 
class foo:
    x: t.Optional[int] = None
    y: t.Optional[int] = None
    z: t.Optional[int] = None
    a: t.Optional[int] = None
    b: t.Optional[int] = None
    c: t.Optional[int] = None

f = foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to need to pass `None` each time, make them keyword arguments:

```py
from typing import Optional

import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass 
class foo:
    x: Optional[int] = None
    y: Optional[int] = None
    z: Optional[int] = None
    a: Optional[int] = None
    b: Optional[int] = None
    c: Optional[int] = None
```

Note that you can still call class `foo` positionally, as in you can calll `foo` like: `foo(1, 2, 3)` and this will be equivalent to calling `foo(x=1, y=2, z=3)`.

It's also a nice habit to type hint as `Optional`, if you're already going to allow `None` as a potential value. Type hinting as `int` implies that there *must* be an int passed.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I already wrote.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `mypy` doesn't treat `x : int = None` as an implicit type hint of `Optional[int]`, like it does for function parameters.

Comment: @chepner. It might be something to do with how `dataclasses` works, if I had to guess. I believe there are some open bugs for how pylint interacts with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Get positional args:

```
pos_args = [None for field_name, field_value in foo.__dataclass_fields__.items() if field_value.default == field_value.default_factory]
```

Init:

```
foo(*args)
```